# Finder Icon to Go to Enclosing Directory

Tags: finder, navigation

Finder icon to to navigate up one level to enclosing directory would make my life so much easier. Especially when I have to move up several directory levels.

I realize there's a keyboard shortcut, but sometimes I navigate via mouse only.

There's also a menu option, but that's more involved than just clicking an icon -- which has been available in Linux & windows forever.

I can't imagine why Apple would not include such a self-evident function, given that they're better in almost every other category of user experience.

There was once an app to create such an icon, but I don't think it goes with High Sierra (up to & including Sierra only).

[image]

<sup>info edited in from deleted 'answer'</sup>

Comment: This is really unclear. What view are you using? What OS? Finder windows all have a hierarchical menu at the top, so long as you didn't hide the Status Bar. A picture may be worth a thousand words...

Comment: @Tetsujin I think he means the Finder Go -> Enclosing folder (option+arrow up) functionality, e.g. from `~/Documents/Example/` to `~/Documents/`. He mentions High Sierra as his OS.

Comment: That's Cmd/↑ - though the OP said 'by mouse' so I'd really like to see a picture of just what & where, precisely.

Comment: You can edit your posts if you use the same account you used to post the question. If you're no longer able to access your other account, you can request an account merge using the contact us link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Deleted 'answer' gives enough info to actually answer the question, so I've edited that into the question & provided an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You must have at some point removed this, as it's there by default.
You've also changed the toolbar to text view only, so it may have happened at that time.

Right click anywhere in that top bar & select Customise Toolbar... [It's also in the Finder View Menu.]

Drag "Path" back into the toolbar.

[image]

Clicking on it reveals the entire hierarchy.

You can also Cmd/click on the folder name/icon, top centre of the Finder window.

Answer (score 0):

The "path" functionality is useful, but I miss the simplicity of the Windows & Linux approach.

I found this discussion of making a "[one-click, up-one-level](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070326144320146)" functionality.

I'm not sure whether these will work on recent Mac OS versions. Basically, you create an AppleScript that adds a 'Go to Parent Folder' button to the toolbar and then save it as an application:

> First create an AppleScript app with just this line of code:
>   Blockquote
>
> ```
> tell application "Finder" to set target of window 1 to the container ¬
> of target of window 1
> ```
>
> Then save it as an application, and quit Script Editor. Now show the
>   contents of the application package you just created by
>   control-clicking on the folder and then choosing Show Package Contents
>   from the pop-up menu. Open the Contents folder and edit the info.plist
>   file in your editor of choice. Adding the following will make the
>   program faceless, so that it does not appear in the Dock when
>   launched:
>
> ```
> <key>NSUIElement</key>
> <string>1</string>
> ```
>
> Finally create a nice icon (I made one in Photoshop that looks similar
>   to the navigation buttons, as seen above right), paste it onto the app
>   (in its Get Info window) and drag the app to the Finder toolbar.